# Our SFSE admins

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

I came across an old metadaddy post on the site today, and I noticed his ♦ moderator star was missing. He also was removed from the [moderators page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

Has he stepped down from his moderator position?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. We're very grateful for all the contributions Pat has done both as a user and Mod. He's moved away from salesforce currently.

Matt and I have been in touch with the stackexchange team, and have agreed that they will host another election for the spot, in the weeks or months to come depending on their schedule and backlog.